# Dspace 6.3 OAI add xml:lang attrubute to oai_dc

Tags: xml, xsd, xls, dspace, oai

I am trying to add the xml:lang attribute to OAI.
I am using "oai_dc" metadata format.

`<dc:title xml:lang="en">English</dc:title>`
`<dc:title xml:lang="fr">France</dc:title>`

I was trying it by adding to oai_dc.xsl

using `<xsl:attribute name="xml:lang"></xsl:attribute>`
or
static way(just to check) `<dc:tiitle xml:lang="en">`

Nothing changes there is no errors too.
When I change `<xsl:attribute **name**="xml:lang"></xsl:attribute>` to `"ref"`
It's says that only name is acceptable.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any advice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything was all right, It was my failure.
I wasn't properly cleaning and re-indexing the cache